# Python beginner slot machine

Tags: python

I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop with this program. I know I need to assign separate values for each random number but I don't know how and my TAs aren't answering their emails. Here's my code:

```py
import random
random_num = random.randint(0, 10) #generates random numbers between 0 and 10
user_input = input('Play again?(Y or N):')

while user_input != 'N':
    print('Python Slot Machine')
    print(random)

    if random_num != random_num and random_num != random_num:
        print('Uh oh! No match this time!')
        print(user_input)
    elif random_num == random_num and random_num != random_num:
        print('You matched two! So close!')
        print(user_input)
    elif random_num == random_num and random_num == random_num and random_num == random_num:
        print('Jackpot!! You matched all 3!')
        print(user_input)
```

Comment: Your `while` loop does not include your `input()`, therefore `user_input` never varies once inside the loop.

Comment: Infinite loop is because you never update `user_input` so the loop continues (you should allow the user to update `user_input` at the end of the loop). Also you should go over these conditions again, only the last one will ever be true (and will always be true).

Comment: Youy want to fix the code such that code ouptut make sense or Just want to fix infinate loop issue>?

Comment: I've fixed the infinite loop issue, that was the biggest one. Now I need to make it make sense. I need to have 3 random integers and have them run like what i have above, but I don't know how to do that. If i define 3 separate integers, they'll stay the same throughout the loop. Do i need to change them inside the loop?

Comment: Regardless of anything, you are never going to get 3 matches from random numbers. There is an entire science and a complicated algorithm to how slot machines work. Randomly picking 3 numbers and expecting them all to ever match is a not realistic, at all. Run this snippet and watch it NEVER get 3 matches `for _ in range(1000):print([random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(3)])`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting stuck in an infinite loops because your `input` function is outside of the loop, so the user never gets to decide whether they want to continue or not.

What you've done in your code above is generated a random number, and then made several references to that random number. Each time you place the variable `randon_num` into your function, it does not generate a new number. Instead, it keeps referencing back to when you defined `random_num`.

A simple way to do this would be to create a function that generates a random number so you don't have to copy the `random.randint()` code every time.

Answer (score 0):

if else statments dont work the way you think they do.
If you have multiple loops, you can't check the value multiple times to address the loops. Also you checked random_num against random_num.

Let me show you another way to do this. Instead of giving the user a way to exit, have him play until the end. After 3 guesses it's game over anyways. For each time the user matched the random_number you give him a point.
You also have to refresh the random number after each try, otherwise it will stay the same. And as you show the number after a loop, the user knows the number from there on.

After three loops you end the while loop and print one of the messages from the messages list using the earned points as index for the list.

```
import random

points = 0
counter = 0
messages = [
    'Uh oh! No match this time!',
    'You only matched one',
    'You matched two! So close!',
    'Jackpot!! You matched all 3!'
]
while counter < 3:
    random_num = random.randint(0, 10)  # generates random numbers between 0 and 10
    user_input = input('Please enter your guess: ')
    print('Python Slot Machine')
    print(f'random number: {random_num}')

    if random_num == int(user_input):
        points += 1
    counter += 1

print(messages[points])
```

Comment: It's not a guessing game. It's a slot machine. You pull the lever, barrels spin, they eventually stop, if they match you win. The OP's `random` method is never going to work no matter how much the code is fixed. The following snippet is almost NEVER going to be the same three numbers, using `random`. `[random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: @OneMadGypsy No idea what you are talking about. I just wrote a little test doing exactly what you say. I ran 100 attempts multiple times on getting the same 3 numbers and created some stats about it. The fastest attempt is between 1 and 2 tries, the slowest attempt is between 400 and 1000 with an average between 110 and 130 tries.
I would say this is somewhat more then "NEVER" right?

Comment: well, I did the same thing 10,000 times, had python tell me how many had three matches, and the answer was 0, every time I ran it. I know how to check if all the items in a list are equal. My check was not wrong. I got 2 out of 3 matches about the amount of times you said. Regardless, slot machines are not random.

Answer (score 0):

Your Logic don't make sense anyway. but, Correct structure is

```
import random
random_num = random.randint(0, 10)

while True:

    user_input = input('Play again?(Y or N):')

    if user_input == "Y":

        #your code
        #your code
        #Your code

    else:
        print("User want to quit")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to restart your project. You are telling the program to check if the same number equals the same number multiple times.

Ex. if the random number is 6, all of the random numbers are going to be 6.

You need to use the `random.sample` function in order to get multiple random numbers differently.

You also need to use functions in order to organize and optimize your code

Here is an example:

```
import random
random_num = random.sample(range(0,10),4)
#generates random numbers between 0 and 10
def playAgain():
    user_input = input('Play again?(Y or N):')

    if user_input.startswith('y'):
        print('Python Slot Machine')
        main()
    else:
        quit()
def main():
    #your code
```